# Empty space for one columns width with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent div and two divs inside. I want to keep specific sizes (columns) for those child divs. Is this possible in flexbox? I'm strugling with this.

```
<div class="parent"> 
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

First child should have width of 1 column, second child width of 2 columns. On right side I want to have empty space in width of 1 column (so parent div should behave like it has 4 columns).

Comment: 25% and 50% width, no?

Comment: @TemaniAfif more less yes, but would be nice to have automatic space between if possible

Comment: Please include your CSS as well, to demonstrate where you're getting stuck.

Comment: then you need CSS grid not flexbox

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you. I think i will do it with grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method using [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) to set flex items to specific percentage widths.

In this example, the two flex items can neither [shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) nor [grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow). Splitting 100% width into four columns, each column needs to be 25% of the parent width. The first item is 25% and the second is 50% (two columns wide), leaving 25% space on the right.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.child {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 25%
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT

I notice you'd like some space between each column. One way is to add some right margin percentage to flex items and subtract that percentage from each item's flex-basis.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.child {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 22%;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 47%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

If you'd rather that the space between columns not be a percentage, you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to calculate the appropriate flex-basis. However, note that this is not supported in IE or Edge at the time of this post.

> IE & Edge are reported to not support calc inside a 'flex'. (Not tested on older versions) 
>   This example does not work: flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 20px);
>   [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.child {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 0.5em);
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 0.5em);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using flexbox by using a *pseudo element* that occupies the fourth column:

- add `flex: 1` to the first `child` and the *pseudo element*,
- add `flex: 2` to the second `child`.

See demo below:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}

.child + .child {
  flex: 2;
}

.parent:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> 
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
```

And the easier solution using CSS Grid layout - establish a 4-column layout and *span* the second `child` element over two columns:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background: lightblue;
}

.child + .child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> 
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nobody seems to have suggested you could just set the width of the parent:

```css
.parent {
 width: 75%;
 display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex: 150;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.child:first-child {
 flex: 75;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> 
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

And to add, you want your second child to be twice as big as your first, so give your second child a `flex` value of something that's twice as big as your first - I used `1` and `2`, but you could've used `flex: 75` and `flex: 150` to achieve the same effect.